# Django - app in subfolder

Tags: python, django

I've created new django app in a subdirectory using the command:

```
python manage.py startapp appName subFolder/appName
```

but if I try to add this app to INSTALLED_APPS at the end of the list I see the following error:

> ImportError: No module named appName

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to include the subfolder when you add the app to `INSTALLED_APPS`, for example:

```
'subFolder.appName',
```

or

```
'subfolder.appName.apps.AppNameConfig',
```

Comment: Was trying, but the console returns "ImportError: No module named subFolder"

Comment: does your subfolder have a `__init__.py` file in it ? if not then create it and leave it empty.

Comment: okay, I had to create the "_init__.py" file in the subfolder. Thanks

Comment: yes.. it is double underscore by the way. To treat a folder as package you need to create an empty `__init__.py` inside it otherwise you won't be able to import that anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

I tried different options but no one can solve that issue.

Finally, I found a solution.

Simply go to the `subFolder/appName/apps.py` file and

replace this line `name = 'appname'` with `name = 'subfolder.appname'`

And then you can simply add to the installed apps list in `settings.py`.

```
'subfolder.appname'
```